# PoolConnection + Singleton + jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, singleton, pool

Realmente necesito algunos consejos. En un proyecto web jsp (jdk8) con servidor Glassfish 4 he decidido dar mantenimiento a los catálogos de mi bd (SQL Server) con una clase de conexión que usa un driver de conexión jdbc4 y extiende a la capa de datos, en cada método abro y cierro la conexión.

```
    package datos;
    import java.sql.*;

    public class Conexion 
    {

    private static Connection cn = null;

    // ACCESO AL SERVIDOR LOCAL
    private static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=db;Persist Security Info=True;";
    private static String user = "user";
    private static String password = "password";

    public Conexion()
    {  

    }

    // Testing
    public static Connection getConnection() 
    {   
       if (EstaConectado()==false) 
           {
                Conexion.CrearConexion();
           }
       return cn;
    }

    public static boolean EstaConectado()
    {
            boolean resp = false;
            try
            {
                    if ((cn==null) || (cn.isClosed()))
                            resp = false;
                    else
                            resp = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e){}

            return resp;
    }

    public static void CrearConexion()
    {
            try 
            {
               Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
               cn= DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
               System.out.println("Se conecto a la Base de Datos");
           } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
               cn=null;
               System.out.println("Error no se puede cargar el driver:" + e.getMessage());
           } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
               cn=null;
               System.out.println("Error al establecer la conexion:" + e.getMessage());
           }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
            new Conexion();
            Conexion.getConnection();
    }

}
```

La clase DT_tbl_cat_Convenios que extiende Conexion:

```
    package datos;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import entidades.tbl_cat_Convenios;

    public class DT_tbl_cat_Convenios extends Conexion 
    {

    ///METODO PARA ELIMINAR UN CONVENIO///
    public boolean eliminarConvenios(int id)
    {
        int x = 0;
        boolean g = false;

        try 
        {

            String SQL = ("UPDATE tbl_cat_Convenios set Estado = 3 where IdConvenios=?");
            Connection cn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement s = cn.prepareStatement(SQL);

            s.setInt(1, id);
            x = s.executeUpdate();
            g = x > 0;

            s.close();
            cn.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("DATOS: ERROR AL ELIMINAR EL CONVENIO!");
        }

        return g;
     }
    }
```

Para los maestros detalle utilizo el Api PoolConnection (org.apache.commons.dbcp) para la gestión de datos, sólo que en esta clase de Conexión uso también el patrón singletón para no instanciar el pool. sin embargo la aplicación se congela pasado de 10 min - 30 min de ejecución.

```
    package datos;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    //import javax.sql.DataSource;
    import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    import datos.PoolConexion;

    public class PoolConexion 
    {

    private static PoolConexion INSTANCE = null;
    private static Connection con = null;
    //private static DataSource dataSource;
    private static BasicDataSource dataSource;

    //SERVIDOR LOCAL
    private static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=bd;Persist Security Info=True;";
    private static String user = "user";
    private static String password = "password";

    private PoolConexion()
    {
        inicializaDataSource();
    }

    private synchronized static void createInstance()
    {
        if(INSTANCE==null)
        {
            INSTANCE = new PoolConexion();
        }
    }

    public static PoolConexion getInstance()
    {
        if(INSTANCE == null)
        {
            createInstance();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

     public final void inicializaDataSource()
        {

            org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource();
            basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            basicDataSource.setUsername(user);
            basicDataSource.setPassword(password);
            basicDataSource.setUrl(url);
            basicDataSource.setMaxActive(50);
            dataSource = basicDataSource;
        }


     public static boolean EstaConectado()
        {
            boolean resp = false;
            try
            {
                con = PoolConexion.dataSource.getConnection();
                if ((con==null) || (con.isClosed()))
                    resp = false;
                else
                    resp = true;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            return resp;
        }

        public static Connection getConnection() 
        {   
           if (EstaConectado()==false) 
               {
                    try 
                    {
                        con = PoolConexion.dataSource.getConnection();
                        System.out.println("se conecto a la bd!!!");
                    } 
                    catch (SQLException e) 
                    {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
               }
           return con;
        }

        public static void closeConnection(Connection con) 
        {   
            if (EstaConectado()!=false) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    con.close();
                    System.out.println("Cerrando la Conexion");
                } 
                catch (SQLException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PoolConexion.getInstance();
            Connection con = null;

            try 
            {
                con = PoolConexion.getConnection();
                if(con!=null)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectado a bd!");
                    System.out.println("Conectado a bd!!!");
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al Conectar a bd!!!");
                    System.out.println("Error al Conectar a bd!!!");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                try 
                {
                   con.close();
                   if ((con==null) || (con.isClosed()))
                       System.out.println("Se desconecto de bd!!!");
                   else
                       System.out.println("Sigue Conectado a bd!!!");

                } 
                catch (SQLException ex) 
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

```
    package datos;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import entidades.Tbl_cat_barrios;
    import vistas.Vw_barrios;

    public class Dt_tbl_barrio 
    {
     PoolConexion pc = PoolConexion.getInstance(); 
     Connection c = null;
     private ResultSet rsBarrio;
     private ResultSet rs;

    // Metodo para llenar el RusultSet
    public void llenaRsBarrio(Connection c)
    {

        try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * from tbl_cat_barrios", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
            rsBarrio = ps.executeQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("DATOS: ERROR EN LISTAR BARRIOS "+ e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

       // Metodo para visualizar todos barrios
        public ArrayList<Vw_barrios> listarBarrios()
        {
            ArrayList<Vw_barrios> listaBarrios = new ArrayList<Vw_barrios>();

            try
            {
                c = PoolConexion.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement("SELECT * from Vw_barrios where estado <> 3", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, ResultSet.HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    Vw_barrios vwb = new Vw_barrios();
                    vwb.setIdBarrio(rs.getInt("id_barrio"));
                    vwb.setIdMunic(rs.getInt("idMunicipio"));
                    vwb.setBarrio(rs.getString("barrio"));
                    vwb.setMunicipio(rs.getString("Descripcion"));
                    listaBarrios.add(vwb);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("DATOS: ERROR EN LISTAR BARRIOS "+ e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                PoolConexion.closeConnection(c);
            }
            return listaBarrios;

        }


      // Metodo para guardar barrios nuevos
        public boolean guardarBarrio(Tbl_cat_barrios tcb)
        {
            boolean guardado = false;

            try
            {
                c = PoolConexion.getConnection();
                this.llenaRsBarrio(c);
                rsBarrio.moveToInsertRow();
                rsBarrio.updateInt("idMunicipio", tcb.getIdMunic());
                rsBarrio.updateString("barrio", tcb.getBarrio());
                rsBarrio.updateInt("estado", 1);
                rsBarrio.insertRow();
                rsBarrio.moveToCurrentRow();
                guardado = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.err.println("ERROR AL GUARDAR BARRIOS "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                PoolConexion.closeConnection(c);
            }

            return guardado;
        }
    }
```

Optimicé el Glassfish para server, con 4096M de RAM y hasta 1024M el MaxpermSize, en la base de datos configuré el tiempo de ejecución de las conexiones con valor "0" porque estoy probando.

Otro punto importante, cuando se congela la aplicación tengo que reiniciar el Glassfish, sin embargo en las últimas pruebas realizadas en producción veo que los catálogos siguen funcionando sin problemas, pero el resto de la aplicación sigue congelada, es decir la parte del pool.

Otro dato importante, en los catálogos hago uso de ArrayList y resultset para mostrar datos y prepare Statements para inserciones y modificaciones de datos pero en los maestros detalles hago uso de únicamente de los Resultset para mostrar, modificar e insertar datos.

Si algún buen samaritano me quiere colaborar, con gusto comparto código para revisar que puedo estar haciendo mal. Talvez tengo que reemplazar algún componente de la arquitectura.

Espero sus observaciones y con gusto vemos el caso.

Saludos

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Ayudaría mucho si pudieses editar la pregunta y añadir en modo texto las partes más relevantes de código donde sospechas que puede estar el problema.

Comment: Por qué estás usando una conexión manual, sin pool, para el update, y luego para el select sí usas el pool? Deberías usar solamente la del pool.

Otra cosa, es importantísimo que cierres las conexiónes una vez que la usaste, en este caso:

Comment: Por otro lado, siempre que cierres recursos debes hacerlo en un bloque finally, porque si hay una excepción, la líneas donde cierras la conexión no se ejecutan nunca, y ahí tienes una potencial causa de que se te congele todo, que te quedes sin conexiones a la BD, y la aplicación se quede esperando en algún sitio a que haya una conexión disponible.

Comment: Leyendo un poco más tu código, veo que estás llamando a dataSource.getConection() en el método EstaConectado(), a su vez, llamas a EstaConectado() cuando quieres obtener una nueva conexión, y cuando quieres cerrar la conexión. Eso significa que por cada consulta a la base de datos, estás obteniendo 3 conexiones, 2 de las cuales no cierras nunca, y es más que probable que después de un tiempo, te quedes sin conexiones a la BD que es lo que causa que tu aplicación falle.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tus comentarios, procederé a actualizar el código y te comento.

Comment: Estimado @Alex quiero comentarte que he actualizado el código siguiendo tus sugerencias y mi aplicación está funcionando exitosamente! :) Muchas Gracias y Bendiciones para tí!

Comment: @elsnergo por nada, puedes entonces agregar que el comentario te resultó útil.